# Неправильная кодировка в MYSQL

Tags: mysql, charset

Запрос `SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM users` выдаёт строковые поля `Collation: latin1_swedish_ci`. Когда выбираю столбец с именами, русские имена выводятся вот в таком виде:

```
 Ð ÑƒÑ
Ð›ÑƒÐ¿Ð¾Ð³Ð»Ð°Ð·
```

Что можно сделать, чтобы в консоли выводилось правильно?

Пробовал:

- менять кодировку клиента (`SET NAMES "UTF-8"`)
- менять кодировку таблицы на utf-8

Comment: тип поля какой? varchar или nvarchar?

Comment: @Kryshtop varchar

Answer (score -1):

Проблема была решена переходом на кодировку Latin1 на клиенте.

Comment: ждите новых проблем. latin1 не кириллическая кодировка. таки надо было правильно применять set names